# Manjaro linux KDE won't launch desktop environment after updating packages

Tags: kde, upgrade, manjaro, pacman

I updated all packages with pacman, and now when I start something goes wrong before the GUI is up. I changed the boot script in grub, added 3 at the end of a line, so I boot into a command shell. When in there I have tried different things, but both when I run `sudo startx` or sudo `kdeinit5` the only error message I get is `error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically telling you there is a missing library/package needed.

Execute: `pacman -Fs libicui18n.so.60` to search for the (absent/missing) package containing that file. Once "discovered", install it — repeat the process for the rest...if any.

You might need to do `pacman -Fy` first to sync the files database.

Comment: I did this, but now I get "error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.59" whenever I try to run pacman

Comment: actually, most of my programs seems to be using this library, what to do?

Comment: Like I said: `repeat the process for the rest...if any`...I don't know any other way to get around this, unless you would like to automate that.